# How to animate elements when it completely enters the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an animation to the h1 element using CSS, now I want the animation to occur when the h1 element comes into the viewport completely when the user scrolls down.

By the time the user scrolls down the page, the animation has already occurred.

I want the animation to occur only when the h1 element enters the viewport by adding the class **.showtext** to the span element.

Cannot set up a proper intersection observer, plz help

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden
}

.page1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.showtext{
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0,100%);

  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>LNPD02</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="page1">
      <h1>Scroll down</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="page2">
      <h1 class="text"><span class="hidetext showtext">Animated Text</span></h1>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) it is a very wonderful javascript library.

Comment: @KunalTanwar yes I know. Actually I needed this kind of animation which is mostly coded using gsap but I made similar animation using just CSS but wanted to trigger it on entering the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it with **javascript**. A function is triggered every time the user scrolls the page. If the `element's position is greater than the screen's top and less than the screen's bottom` that is **in the viewport**, toggle the classes to make the animaiton.

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.text')
function scrolListener(e){
  var screenTop = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  var screenBottom = screenTop + innerHeight;
  var textTop = text.getBoundingClientRect().top
  
  if ( textTop < screenBottom && textTop < screenTop)
  {
    text.children[0].classList.add("showtext");
    text.children[0].classList.remove("hidetext");
  }
  
}


document.onscroll = scrolListener
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text span {
  transition: .3s;
}


.showtext {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s;
}
.hidetext {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}


@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>LNPD02</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="page1">
    <h1>Scroll down</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="page2">
    <h1 class="text"><span class="hidetext">Animated Text</span></h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make the animation trigger only once ? Like after the user triggers the animation once, it can't be triggered again until and unless the user reloads the page again. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Now, by removing the `else if` and `else` loop, the job can be done.

Comment: Many Thanks! Just wanted this