Animate Count of Number when element in Viewport in pure CSS
My goal is to start a number counter from 0 to 100 as soon as the number enters the viewport.
With my current solution, I have two issues:

The number jumps back to 0 once it finished counting to 100
The counting doesn't "start" when the element enters the viewport, but rather depends on the scroll state. It counts the further the user scrolls.

Here is my code:
@property --num {
    syntax: "<integer>";
    initial-value: 0;
    inherits: false;
  }

    .number {
      animation-name: counter;
      animation-duration: 5s; 
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
      animation-delay: 0s;
      animation-direction: normal;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-fill-mode: none;
      animation-timeline: view();
      counter-reset: num var(--num);
      font: 800 40px system-ui;
      padding: 2rem;
    }
    .number::after {
      content: counter(num);
    }

    @keyframes counter {
      from {
        --num: 0;
      }
      to {
        --num: 100;
      }
    }



    <span class="number"></span>



I'm not clear on your actual requirement. Do you want the animation to start when the element enters the viewport and continue regardless of scroll position? OR, should the animation start when entering the viewport and then be based on how far the user has scrolled and stop/start with scrolling?

From your comments I think it's the latter in which case animation-timeline is not what you want here (I think), you will need javascript.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826638/how-to-animate-elements-when-it-completely-enters-the-viewport

Look into IntersectionObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver - I don't think a completely CSS solution is possible, tho' you can start the animation with view() it only seems to continue on scrolling.

...and animation-timeline is not completely supported (e.g. no FF or Safari) so I'd settle for a few lines of JS currently.

@Paulie_D I want the animation to start when the element enters the viewport and continue regardless of the scroll position.

@AHaworth thanks, yes I see. I think you are right, I will need some JS additionally

You need to define the animation range. In your case, animation-range: entry 100% exit 0%;. The consider forwards or both to make sure the final value remain after the animation ends


@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.number {
  animation: counter linear both;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range: entry 100% exit 0%;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  margin-block: 150vh;
}

.number::after {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 100;
  }
}
<div class="number"></div>



